# Java: weird issue with iterator

Tags: java, sql, iterator

I am having a weird problem with an iterator I don't fully understand.
The iterator is being used in a loggedPreparedStatement but every now and then (about 20 of the 200) throws this error:

```
SQLException in executeQuery, errorcode: 0, SQL state: 07001, message: No value specified for parameter 1
while executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement@11fffa73: SELECT ac.id as i FROM ac LEFT JOIN pa ON pa.id = ac.adspace_id WHERE  pa.adspace_id IN (** NOT SPECIFIED **)
```

This is how I create my iterator:

```
private Iterator< Integer > adspacesId = null;

public ArrayList<Integer> getIds(int inAdspaceId) {
        if (inAdspaceId <= 0) return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        tempList.add(new Integer(inAdspaceId));
        adspacesId = tempList.listIterator();
        num = tempList.size();
        activeOnly = false;

        if (adspacesId != null && adspacesId.hasNext() && num > 0) {
            executeQuery();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

So I add an int to a temp arrayList and then turn that into a Iterator, then use that iterator in my query like so:

```
LoggedPreparedStatement statement = new LoggedPreparedStatement(theQuery.toString());
statement.setInt(1, adspacesId);
```

So my first guess would be, no entries in my iterator, but how does it pass the check of adspacesId.hasNext() then?

The value of num is 1, so there is an entry in the templist and I would assume in my iterator.

Little help is welcome :)

Comment: `my first guess would be, no entries in my iterator` - can you print/log your `adspacesId` Iterator inside `executeQuery()`? And, how does `executeQuery()` look like? And, what is the `LoggedPreparedStatement` anyway?

Comment: have you tried to debug this one yet? additionally i am not sure, if you set the value of the prepared statement the right way.

Comment: You seem to be passing an `Iterator<Integer>` in `statement.setInt(1,adspacesId)`.... I guess it shd be `statement.setInt(1,adspacesId.next())`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

Iterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();

System.out.println("First Element : " + it.next());
```

I guess you have to call **next()** to get the elements even the first one. Which i don't see you have done here. And if its a **PreparedStatement**, I don't see where you have added the parameter before executing the **executeQuery()**, And i suggest you use the **ListIterator** interface instead just **Iterator** here..